# Debug.Writeline and/or Console.Writeline to RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, console, richtextbox

Is it possible to stream `Debug.Writeline` and/or `Console.Writeline` to a RichTextBox control in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

If so, what would be the best method of doing so?

Comment: is the console/debug call being made within the same application as the RichTextBox, or are you trying to load a console application and want to display its output in your RTB?

Comment: then this link may help you in redirecting your console.stdout to another stream, which you could then pipe into your RTB: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm having trouble understanding, but how will I be able to get the richtextbox to update anytime more content get's added to the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `TextWriter` and set the `Console` output to that, meaning you can intercept any Writes. To make it more generalised, you could pass in a delegate so any action could be supported in the future, not just updating your `RichTextBox`.

For instance:

```
class InterceptingWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextWriter _existingWriter;
    Action<string> _writeTask;

    public InterceptingWriter(TextWriter existing, Action<string> task)
    {
        _existingWriter = existing;
        _writeTask = task;
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        // This outputs to the console. Remove it if you only want output to
        // appear in your control
        _existingWriter.WriteLine(value);
        // This calls the delegate you passed in to the constructor, updating 
        // your textbox or anything else that acts upon the string passed in
        _writeTask(value);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    // ...other overrides as necessary...
}
```

And in the callee:

```
Console.SetOut(new InterceptingWriter(Console.Out, (str) => UpdateMyTextBox(str));
```

Now whenever you call `Console.WriteLine`, the string will be output to the console and your `UpdateMyTextBox` method will also be called with the same string, letting you update the UI accordingly.

As for the `Debug` output, you can write a listener to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y5y10s7.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the C# code. I missed that the question was tagged VB.NET. You can use an online converter to translate it for you: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: I've tried translating this to vb.net but I can't fix It. how can you call It ?